# x86 jump to an address

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

As an assignment for a security class, I am trying to use `__asm__("jmp 0xbffff994");` in my code, but when I disassemble things in gdb, the instruction is changed to `jmp 0xc8047e2a`.
Any idea why and how can I jump to a particular address?

Comment: Why the heck do you need to jump to a raw address? I'm having a hard time understanding any possible (non-nefarious) use for that.

Comment: @kquinn regardless, his question has been asked, let's try to answer it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Probably because it's a jumping to a relative address, and the linker or loader has moved your code.  Try putting the address into a variable, and then do:

```
jmp dword [var]
```

or alternatively:

```
push 0xbffff994
ret
```

Comment: *that* is the correct answer, also note that: "mov eax, 0x11223344; jmp eax"; will also work and is likely the most straight forward.

Comment: very true, but he might be using fastcall (I'm not sure of the significance of 0xbffff994).

Comment: 0xbffff994 likely = a location on the stack on a linux box :-P

Comment: You don't want `push/ret` for performance.  It unbalances the return-address predictor stack.  (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546141/jmp-to-absolute-address-op-codes#comment104329413_2049606), and https://agner.org/optimize/ / http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/).  Use `mov eax, 0xbffff994` / `jmp eax` or see [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19552158)

Comment: Performance is usually very low on the list of priorities for shellcode.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing - if you are patching very hot code paths, you do care about performance

Comment: > As an assignment for a security class

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to determine the exact address upon compile time, have you tried using labels? It is much more common to use them with jmp.

example:

```
start:
 jmp exit

exit:
 ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Explains why your jump is not the same you programmed. It has to do with object files and linking.

if you want to jump to a particular address, it's best to patch the jump using a Debugger or Disassembler.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (gcc version 4.2.4, Ubuntu) this looks fine on the disassmbley (insight):

```
int main()
{
asm("jmp 0xbffff994"); 
return 0;
};
```

results of the disassmbley (insight):

```
        0x8048344       :                 lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
-       0x8048348       :               and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
-       0x804834b       :               pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
-       0x804834e       :              push   %ebp
-       0x804834f       :              mov    %esp,%ebp
-       0x8048351       :              push   %ecx
-       0x8048352       :              jmp    0xbffff994
-       0x8048357       :              mov    $0x0,%eax
-       0x804835c       :              pop    %ecx
-       0x804835d       :              pop    %ebp
-       0x804835e       :              lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
-       0x8048361       :              ret
```

Comment: I would guess that that disassembler is showing the offset of the jmp and not its actual target. (the jmp instruction takes an offset relative to eip when you give it a 32-bit immediate operand).

Comment: Why would you guess that? is there a way to test it? it is running as a graphical interface with GDB below.

Comment: Or it could be that there's no relocation.  However, if you dump the opcodes with the assembly you'll be able to see the offset.

Comment: I see this 
8048352: e9 3d 76 fb b7        jmp    bffff994 <_end+0xb7fb6454>
can't find the _end label, but it looks mighty close to the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a hex editor and simply changing the value if it's just a one time thing.