# How to jump to memory location in intel syntax for both x64 and x32

Tags: assembly, x86, clang, x86-64, gnu-assembler

How would I jump to a known memory address in intel assembly syntax (both x32 and x64).

I think I have the 64 bit syntax down. For example, if in x64 I wanted to jmp to the code at `0x75767` and I was located at `0000`, I would do:

```
0000: FF 25 01 00 00 00         jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x75761]
```

Is that ^ correct? I thought I could dissemble those bytes that into x32 instruction using objdump `objdump.exe -D -Mintel,i386 -b binary -m i386 test.bin` which results in:

```
jmp    DWORD PTR 0x75761
```

Then just use `clang++.exe -masm=intel -m32 -c test.o` to convert this instruction to x32 bytes but it says:

```
error: invalid operand for instruction
jmp DWORD PTR 0x75761
^
```

I want to avoid writing into any registers.

Is my x64 jmp instruction correct?

How would I accomplish something similar in x32? Let's say in x32 I need to jmp to `0x400107` and I'm at `0x400000`

I'm messing around with tweaking running process memory on Windows. Forgive me if my question has inaccuracies, I'm learning.

Comment: Already your first code is wrong. You can clearly see it uses 32 bit offset not 64.  If you want to jump to an absolute address then in 64 bit mode use an embedded pointer addressed rip relative. In 32 bit mode you can use the `push`+`ret` trick. If you know the offset you can of course encode that directly.

Comment: All addressing modes you can use take a 32 bit displacement, so the jump target has to be within ±2 GiB of where the jump instruction is.  So no, the instruction is not correct: the displacement you desire is out of range.

Comment: I sorta noticed that when I just wrote this. Let me modify.

Comment: @Jester so you're saying I could do `push 0x75767` and then `ret` if I wanted to get to `0x75767` ? (for x32) If so will that mess the stack up for future execution?

Comment: Since `ret` removes the address pushed, no, it does not mess up the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear whether you need assembly or machine code. If you want to jump to an absolute address then in 64 bit mode use an embedded pointer addressed rip relative:

```
jmp [rip+foo]
foo: .quad target_address
```

Machine code: `ff 25 00 00 00 00 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx` (with the last 8 bytes being the target absolute address).
The first 6 are the instruction, with 2 byte encoding the `jmp` opcode + modrm, and the 4 after that being `rel32=0`, so the load address is 0 bytes past the end of the whole instruction.

Or if you can spare a register, `mov r11, OFFSET target_address` / `jmp r11`, or pick any register you can modify.  This is often better performance than doing a data load from code, which normally won't be hot in L1d cache or L1dTLB (but probably is in L2 and maybe L2TLB.  Normally you'd want to put the `.quad` constant somewhere else, along with other read-only data, if that's convenient.)

---

In 32 bit code you can use the `push`+`ret` trick if you are not worried about branch prediction:

```
push offset target_address
ret
```

Machine code: `68 xx xx xx xx c3`

If you can calculate the relative address you can of course just use a normal `jmp` which is `e9 xx xx xx xx` with the last 4 bytes being the distance to jump (counted from the byte following the instruction, where execution would normally continue).

If performance does matter, `mov eax, offset target_address` / `jmp eax` is a pretty standard way.  (Any register works if you don't need its value at this point.)

Comment: Nice, I think this could do the trick. I'll have to test this out.

Comment: What assembler uses the syntax `[rip+foo]`? In nasm it would be `[rel foo]` and in gas it would be `(%rip+foo)`.

Comment: @ChrisMan: Note that `[rip+foo]` targets `foo` using relative addressing, but `[rip+0x75761]` uses `0x75761` literally as an offset relative to the end of this instruction.  So they're interpreted differently.  See [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872)

Comment: @prl: GAS/clang `.intel_syntax noprefix`; like the question said, it's using clang to assemble.

Comment: @ChrisMan: Fun fact: GAS assembles `jmp     0x75761` to a relative jump to reach that absolute address from wherever it ends up at link time.  It works in a `gcc -nostdlib -static -m32 foo.s` executable, but unfortunately clang doesn't support it.  But it doesn't get a runtime fixup to make it work properly in a non-PIE executable, so it's kinda hacky.  [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19552158)

Comment: @Jester wait so `ff 25 00 00 00 00 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx` would be a jmp to an absolute address?

Comment: Yes, that is an absolute address. Only the pointer is addressed relative :)

Comment: Yup, that did the trick in both cases. push ret for x32 was too ez. Thanks!